# Current best practices for detecting Unit Root in time series data?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm trying to get an overview of what are the current best practices for detecting unit roots in time series data.

The main approach I came across is the Augmented Dickey Fuller (ADF) test, which tests for unit roots in three models:

\begin{align}
\Delta y_t =& \alpha + \beta t + \gamma X_{t-1} + \delta_1 \Delta y_{t-1} + \dots + \varepsilon_t \\
\Delta y_t =& \alpha + \gamma X_{t-1} + \delta_1 \Delta y_{t-1} + \dots + \varepsilon_t \\
\Delta y_t =& \gamma X_{t-1} + \delta_1 \Delta y_{t-1} + \dots + \varepsilon_t
\end{align}

If I understand this test correctly, the only reason to not only use the most complex model is that the power to reject H0: $\gamma = 0$ is very low if the complex model is misspecified (i.e., no drift / linear trend).

However, from here on, there seem to be different ways to execute this. One is to go through a kind of flow-chart of consecutive hypothesis tests from the most complex model to the least complex one (see e.g., PDF page in [this book](https://new.mmf.lnu.edu.ua/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/enders_applied_econometric_time_series.pdf)). Another one seems to use model selection, e.g., using an information criterion, and then perform the hypothesis test using the selected model (see e.g., [this paper](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/JES-09-2020-0469/full/html)).

My question is whether there is any agreement based on theory and/or simulation studies which approach works best? In addition, is the ADF even considered best practices? What are, e.g., econometricians using in 2022 to detect a unit root?